# Programmatically create service bus subscription using .net standard

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, .net-standard

My scenario:  Website hosted on the cloud, where each instance creates a subscription to a Service Bus Topic for itself to listen for messages.

My question:  **How do I programmatically create subscriptions?**

Comment: I hear you. Have been asking for management operations since day one. Good news is that the team is listening. Perhaps to make it more realistic, it will take time. Suggest to voice your opinion in the GitHub issue I've linked in my answer.

Comment: Josh, you could consider marking Gustavo's answer as the accepted answer, as it will help others that land on this question.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.3.1.0 allows to create a ManagementClient using the ConnectionString.

```
private async Task CreateTopicSubscriptions()
{
    var client = new ManagementClient(ServiceBusConnectionString);
    for (int i = 0; i < Subscriptions.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!await client.SubscriptionExistsAsync(TopicName, Subscriptions[i]))
        {
            await client.CreateSubscriptionAsync(new SubscriptionDescription(TopicName, Subscriptions[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @josh, I am glad to find this question and not be the one going through this frustration. Definitely he experience is way better now, like actually usable.

Comment: This was very difficult to find.  SO FTW!

Comment: What about SqlFilter? Can you also add it in the code?

Comment: Any word on how the equivalent would be done for EventHubs?

Comment: As SubscriptionExistsAsync and CreateSubscriptionAsync both perform REST calls in the background, there is a race -- if the subscription is created between the two calls, the second calls fails with an exception. Don't know how to solve it, though, as I cannot find anything with the "create if not exists" semantics.

Comment: @Palec I think since Create is enclosed in a conditional, the await must return for Exists prior to code continuing.

Comment: Yes, @Still.Tony. But there still is the race I described. Consider two instances of the same code executing the same instructions at the same time. Both check if the subscription exists, both try to create the subscription -- only one may succeed, the other fails with an exception.

Comment: @GustavoArmenta this is no longer valid as https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus has been deprecated. As the accepted answer could you please edit to reflect that this is no longer the preferred solution?

Answer (score 6):

Original plan for the new Azure Service Bus client was not to include management plane at all and use Azure Active Directory route instead. This has proven to be too problematic, just like you've pointed out. Microsoft messaging team has put together a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-bus-dotnet-management/) to demonstrate the basic operations.

Note that there's a [pending PR](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-bus-dotnet-management/pull/14) to get it working with .NET Core 2.0

Moving forward, it was recognized that developers prefer to access Service Bass using a connection string like they used to over Azure Active Directory option. [Management Operations issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/65) is raised to track requests. [Current plan](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/65#issuecomment-338874419) is to provide a light weight management library for the .NET Standard client.

For now, the options are either to leverage the old client to create entities or use Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus (or Fluent) until the management package is available.

**Update**

Management operations were released as part of 3.1.0 version of the client.

Comment: Accepting this answer because while it didn't solve the technical problem, it addresses the underlying WTF-itude of the state of the libraries right now.

Comment: @josh you're hilarious :) Completely agree about the frustration level. Please chime in on the issue. You'll find ASB team listening and taking action.

Comment: @SeanFeldman, I think Gustavo's answer should now become the excepted answer.

Comment: @RajRao I'm not sure what do you expect me to do. This is the issue with SO - the answer was provided in the context of the question. When the question was asked, there was no `ManagementClient` yet. So the answer was correct **at that point in time**. I can only ammend my answer to indicate that the plan has been implemented.

Comment: Also, the issue I've linked to was closed in 3.1.0, which is when the `ManagementClient` was released. Cheers.

Comment: @SeanFeldman, you are correct. Sorry, somehow, I thought, you had asked the question!

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus has been deprecated. The new option is [Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/) and ManagementClient has been replaced by [ServiceBusAdministrationClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.servicebusadministrationclient?view=azure-dotnet).

```
string connectionString = "<connection_string>";
ServiceBusAdministrationClient client = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(connectionString);
```

This new package also supports ManagedIdentity:

```
string fullyQualifiedNamespace = "yournamespace.servicebus.windows.net";
ServiceBusAdministrationClient client = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(fullyQualifiedNamespace, new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

A little example:

```
var queueExists = await _administrationClient.QueueExistsAsync(queueName);
        if(!queueExists)
            await _administrationClient.CreateQueueAsync(queueName);
```

More info [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/MigrationGuide.md).